# jQuery dialog and css set issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I am working with [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/):

When the dialog opens, Firebug shows...

`<div id="dialog" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 274px;">`,

...but I need to set the width to 346px.

1. I tried using `$("#dialog").css({width : '346px'})`, but this does not work.  After setting the width via `.css()`, Firebug continues to show `width: auto`.
2. I even hard-coded the style attribute as `<div id='dialog' style="width:346px">`, but this does not work! Firebug continues to show `width: auto`.

Can someone please tell what is wrong in my code? How should I set the width of this dialog div? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
        width:'346px'
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/75xzH/1/

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way:

```
$("dialog").dialog({
     "modal": true, 
     "width": 346, 
     "height": 400
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This must work

```
$("#dialog").attr('style','width:346px');
```

This makes sure that your CSS is applied and later this inline style overrides your CSS making the `width:346 px;` as you want.